# PostgreSQL condition: one table equals another

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have seen commands like `DELETE FROM A USING B WHERE A=B` in PostgreSQL scripts. Can anyone point me a reference and explain the logic behind the `A=B`? Is it a good way to match all columns of two tables? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a form of `JOIN` -- because Postgres doesn't support "join" for this purpose.

The equivalent `SELECT` would be:

```
select . . .
from a join
     b
     on a.a = b.b;
```

You can also express this using a correlated subquery:

```
delete from a
    where exists (select 1 from b where b.b = a.a);
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Do you known what's the name of this type of join?

Comment: @Luke . . . In the first query, it is an "inner join".  The `exists` implements a "semi-join".

Comment: Sorry I meant the whole table comparison `A = B`. What's the name of that join? I really wish to find an official document from PostgreSQL, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: @Luke . . . If you are using `a` and `b` as tuples, it is still an inner join, just comparing records instead of individual values.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, but I didn't use `a` and `b` as tuples. I'll try to dig deeper into the PostgreSQL docs.

Comment: @Luke . . . If you are using the table alias without `.`, then you are referring to the full record aka "tuple".